# Is it possible to intersect multiple polygon shapefiles to identify areas where two or more layers overlap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, overlay, overlapping-features, union

I have 19 polygon shapefile layers, with some occasionally overlapping with one another. As a final output, I would like a shapefile that includes only the overlapping areas between 2 or more of these 19 layers (and if it could keep their respective attributes, that would be fantastic).

The Intersect tool provides an ideal output, yet if I add all 19 layers as the inputs, it searches for areas where *all* 19 intersect. The only remedy I can currently imagine is doing pairwise intersections, which would mean I'd have to do it **171** times, then merge them all into one shapefile layer.

I cannot seem to find a method for what I want to do that doesn't involve painful pairwise analyses.

Comment: Unioning all 19 (without attributes) is the best way to do this, since having a single table with FID1,FID2,FID3... allows you to increment a COUNT field for each non-negative FID.  At which point you could select out those  features with a COUNT of 2 or greater.  Probably not more than one page of ArcPy code.  Attributes could be accessed through joins.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Vince:

> Unioning all 19 (without attributes) is the best way to do this, since
>   having a single table with FID1,FID2,FID3... allows you to increment a
>   COUNT field for each non-negative FID. At which point you could select
>   out those features with a COUNT of 2 or greater. Probably not more
>   than one page of ArcPy code. Attributes could be accessed through
>   joins.